# How do I pass a Python list of strings and numbers to JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, python, json, list, flask

I am using  flask and javascript. I need to pass a python list like this:

```
percentage=["John",89]
```

My flask code is like this:

```
@app.route(/graph):
def graph():
    percentage=["John",89]
    return render_template("graph.html",percentage=percentage)
```

Although my javascript performs other functions. I simply tried to display the values being passed. But it does not get displayed at all.

```
<script>
     document.write({{percentage}});
</script>
```

The value passed is getting displayed using html paragraph tag.This works:

```
<p>{{percentage}}</p>
```

I have tried using json.dumps(percentage) but it is not working. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: `percentage|tojson|safe` works; it'll produce a JS-compatible list. **However**, take into account that `document.write()` wants strings, not lists!

Comment: What output were you expecting to see?

Comment: Actually my code has a larger dictionary consisting of names and percentages. So i want to be able to print it using my JavaScript.

Comment: Thank you  @MartijnPieters     percentage|tojson|safe       worked!